# Which carbocation from following is stable by hyperconjugation?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: Please see the picture for figures]

These are the 4 figures, how to tell which one of them is stable by hyperconjugation? A B C all are stable by resonance if im not wrong but which one is by hyperconjugation too?

Comment: Hyperconjugative stabilization is such that it cannot be depicted using delocalization of $\pi$ electrons, but instead uses the breaking of a $\sigma$ bond in the resonance structure (if you use resonance structures to depict at all). I'll let you try to figure out which of the options fits this pattern.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that in the limit, hyperconjugative stabilization may just be a group migration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should probably be option C as in one of its resonating structures, there is an alpha hydrogen(as it is saturated) wrt the carbocation formed. Hence, it can show hyper conjugation

Comment: I wouldn't say C is totally wrong, but it is definitely not the best answer.